# How do you refresh an HTML5 datalist using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html-datalist

I'm loading options into an HTML5 `datalist` element dynamically. However, the browser attempts to show the `datalist` before the options have loaded. This results in the list not being shown or sometimes a partial list being shown. Is there any way to refresh the list via JavaScript once the options have loaded?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="ingredient" list="ingredients">
<datalist id="ingredients"></datalist>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#ingredient").on("keyup", function(event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/ingredients",
        data: {search: value.length > 0 ? value + "*" : ""},
        success: function(ingredients) {
            $("#ingredients").empty();
            for (var i in ingredients) {
                $("<option/>").html(ingredients[i].name).appendTo("#ingredients");
            }
            // Trigger a refresh of the rendered datalist
        }
    });
});
```

Note: In Chrome and Opera, the entire list is only shown if the user clicks on the input after entering text. However, I'd like the entire list to appear *as* the user types. Firefox is not a problem, as it appears to refresh the list automatically when the options are updated.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure this question has a satisfactory answer, as I believe this is simply a shortcoming of certain browsers. If a `datalist` is updated, the browser *should* refresh the list, but some browsers (including Chrome and Opera) simply do not do this. Hacks?

Comment: Can't you hide or disable the list at page load, get the options, and than undisable/unhide the list?

Comment: @Thijs: I'm updating the list on `keyup` events, so it's quite dynamic. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: perhaps always show one item which says "loading..." or some sort of spinning image?

Comment: I found this example http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/6/14/Example-of-a-dynamic-HTML5-datalist-control but I don't know if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks @Ragnar. His solution suffers the same problem. If you open his demo and then type "mo", then hit backspace, the list fails to update in time (but if you inspect element, the `datalist` *has* updated). Works fine in Firefox though.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Chrome, because it works for all other browsers

Comment: Actually, Firefox seems to be the *only* browser that handles it correctly. Neither Chrome nor Opera refresh the list properly. Bummer.

Answer (score 9):

Quite a long time after question but I found a workaround for IE and Chrome (not tested on Opera and already OK for Firefox).

The solution is to focus the input at the end of success (or done) function like this :

```
$("#ingredient").on("keyup", function(event) {
var _this = $(this);
var value = _this.val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/ingredients",
    data: { search: value.length > 0 ? value + "*" : "" },
    success: function(ingredients) {
        $("#ingredients").empty();
        for (var i in ingredients) {
           $("<option/>").html(ingredients[i].name).appendTo("#ingredients");
        }
        // Trigger a refresh of the rendered datalist
        // Workaround using focus()
        _this.focus();
    }
});
```

It works on Firefox, Chrome and IE 11+ (perhaps 10).

Comment: While testing I've found that Firefox stops displaying the suggestions if you type too fast. You don't even need to make async requests for it to happen, I could reproduce it with `setTimeout` as well. Typing one character at a time works, but type more than one before the suggestions are updated and the suggestions won't show up at all. Chrome works fine, so I'd say that Firefox support is currently unstable.

Comment: @Stijn add `autoComplete="off"` to the input field to _fix_ that

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when updating datalist.

The new values would not show until new input event.

I tried every suggested solutions but nothing using Firefox and
updating datalist via AJAX.

However, I solved the problem (for simplicity, I'll use your example):

```
<input type="text" id="ingredient" list="ingredients" **autocomplete="off"**>
<datalist id="ingredients"></datalist>

$("#ingredient").on("**input**", function(event) { ....}
```

Autocomplete and input is the couple that solve my problems and it works with Chrome too.

Comment: I don't know why the comment lost a piece:                                             <input type="text" id="ingredient" list="ingredients" autocomplete="off">
<datalist id="ingredients"></datalist>

Answer (score 1):

You can probably eliminate the problem if you don't make AJAX request on every key stroke. You can try throttle technique using `set/cleatTimeout` to issue request after 500ms after the last char typed:

```
$("#ingredient").on("keyup", function(event) {

    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));

    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {

        var value = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/ingredients",
            data: {search: value.length > 0 ? value + "*" : ""},
            success: function(ingredients) {
                $("#ingredients").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
                    $("<option/>").html(ingredients[i].name).appendTo("#ingredients");
                }
            }
        });

    }, this), 500));
});
```

Comment: I agree that the timeout is a good idea, but it's solving a different problem. The browser still attempts to show the list before the options have finished being appended.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: sounds good, but I recommend you use native bind, and avoid proxy.. `function() {}.bind(this)` ... or `function(param) { console.log(param.name); }.bind(this, {name: "Jason Bourne"});`

Answer (score 1):

[Yoyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5770363/yoyo) gave the correct solution, but here's a better way to structure your inserts into the DOM.

```
$("#ingredient").on("keyup", function(event) {
var _this = $(this);
var value = _this.val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/ingredients",
    data: { search: value.length > 0 ? value + "*" : "" },
    success: function(ingredients) {
        var options = ingredients.map(function(ingredient) {
          var option = document.createElement('option');
          option.value = ingredient.name;
          return option;
        });
        $("#ingredients")
          .empty()
          .append(options);
        // Trigger a refresh of the rendered datalist
        // Workaround using focus()
        _this.focus();
    }
});
```

#### Less DOM manipulation

With this refinement, I'm only inserting into the DOM a single time per each successful callback. This cuts down on the browser needing to re-render, and will help improve any "blips" in the view.

#### Functional Programming and Less Idiomatic jQuery

Here we are using the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to clean up some of the jQuery and make things a bit less idiomatic. You can see from the [ECMA Chart](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Array.prototype.map) that this function will work in all browsers you are targeting.

#### Not Hacky

This by no means is hacky. IE appears to be the only browser that doesn't automatically refresh the input to display the new list options. focus() is just a way to ensure the input is refocused which forces a refresh of the view.

This solution works very well in all of the browsers that my company has to support internally, IE10+ Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I found it worked for me! However, for my scenario I was only wanting to refresh the list if the input was at least 2 characters, pressing backspace also worked up to the point I still had 2 or more characters however less than 2 calling empty then focus did not work! My workaround was as someone else suggested was put in a dummy option (e.g. Type min. 2 chars.). Strangely the dummy item showed when I had no characters but disappeared when I had 1 character in IE 11 at least. Anyhow this is good enough!

Answer (score 0):

Place your #ingredients element is inside #container and try this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/ingredients",
    data: {search: value.length > 0 ? value + "*" : ""},
    success: function(ingredients) {
        $("#ingredients").remove();
        var item = $('<datalist id="ingredients"></datalist>');
        for (var i in ingredients) {                
            item.append("<option>"+ ingredients[i].name +"</option>");
        }
        item.appendTo('#container');
    }
});
```

even better without #container and using jQuery replaceWith():

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/ingredients",
    data: {search: value.length > 0 ? value + "*" : ""},
    success: function(ingredients) {
        var item = $('<datalist id="ingredients"></datalist>');
        for (var i in ingredients) {                
            item.append("<option>"+ ingredients[i].name +"</option>");
        }
        $("#ingredients").replaceWith(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `#container` referring to?

Comment: I think you mean `<datalist>` instead of `<select>`, but I see what you mean. You're suggesting that I replace the entire `datalist` instead of simply replacing the options. I'll try that...

Comment: #container is an element for placing #ingredients element

Comment: thanks @David, is `<datalist>` instead of `<select>`

Comment: This was a good suggestion and definitely worth a try, but unfortunately the behavior is the same. I'm still getting partial lists (and sometimes no list at all).

Comment: Even better: use the `jqXHR.done()` function instead of the deprecated `jqXHR.success` counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

***Your issue*** is that the AJAX is **asynchronous**.

You'd actually have to have a **callback** for the AJAX which you call `onSuccess` which would then update the datalist.  Of course, then you might not have great performance/still have a "skipping" behavior, where your datalist options are lagging behind.

If your list of items from the AJAX isn't too large, you should:
 1. load the ENTIRE list into memory array with the first query, then...
 1. use a filtering function that is applied to the array each time you have a `keyUp` event.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution tested only on GNOME Web (WebKit) that consist on set the 'list' attribute of the input element to empty string and, inmediately after, set it again with the id of the datalist element. Here is the example, supose that your input element is stored in a variable named `input_element`:

```
var datalist = document.getElementById(input_element.list.id);
// at this point input_element.list.id is equals to datalist.id
// ... update datalist element here
// And now the trick:
input_element.setAttribute('list','')
input_element.setAttribute('list',datalist.id)
```