# Why auto complete does not work in this example with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement an auto complete dropdown with dynamic data but it doesnt display any suggestions in the dropdown. I am using this example - Datalists: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/form-control/
which works fine with predefined option tags.

```
<label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Datalist example</label>
   <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
   <datalist id="datalistOptions">
       ... dynamic data here
   </datalist>
```

I do receive data from the PHP script and they are correctly accessed but I think the problem might be due to the delay of the fetch. HTML might expect the data to already be there when loaded. That's why maybe it works with existing  data.

here is the javacsript code inside the fetch function where I dynamically produce the  tags:

```
 var select = document.getElementById("datalistOptions");
 select.innerHTML = "";

 for (var key in data['result']) {
    var val = data['result'][key];
    if (data['result'].hasOwnProperty(key) && key != "error") {
       var val = data['result'][key];
      
       if (val != "") {
          var option = document.createElement("option");              
          option.value = val.id;
          select.appendChild(option);
       }
    }
 }
```

Update: I changed the js code a bit. Now it uses appendChild instead of add function. The previous one was not adding any options to the datalist. appendChild does add options to the list but it does not display them.

Comment: and how do you call to the js script that produces the list? Check the HTML source - does it appears fine there?

Comment: @TomerE please read my update

Comment: Your update does not answer the question yet, where/when/how you actually call this. Does the shown code run on page load, or when the user is already typing into the field, or ...?

Comment: @CBroe the code runs when on user type. So when user starts typing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610752/how-do-you-refresh-an-html5-datalist-using-javascript has a couple of approaches to handle this.

Comment: @CBroe none of them worked, they might be old. They use .focus which is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simpler version of what you trying to do.
Try to take it, add your conditions, and make that data come in that form if you can.

```
     var data = ["Haifa","Tel Aviv","Jerusalem"];
        var select = document.getElementById("datalistOptions");
        select.innerHTML = "";
        for (var key in data) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.label = data[key];
                option.value = data[key];
                select.appendChild(option);
          }
```

And make sure you adds onclick event that calls you script, maybe this is you problem, that you not calling the script - I would recomand somethig like that:

```
<input onclick="datalistCreate()" class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
```

datalistCreate() is the function name in the script.

Comment: did you test it? Does it work? not on my computer

Comment: and of course I am calling the script, I said that I am receiving data back. Thats not a problem

Comment: Yeah it works.
Can you add your code so we can see where it fails?

Comment: it doesnt really fail, it just doesnt display the suggested info below the input. But when I inspect it, the option tags are there.

Comment: I tested yours, it does work but if I place it inside an assynchronous fetch() function then it doesnt, maybe because of the delay of receiving the data from the server

Comment: so annoying, the problem was that the val.id is actually a number, and for some reasons that doesnt work. I swicthed to a text value and it works now, thanks